# Render quarto document with both R and python code

Tags: python, r, rstudio, quarto

I'm using quarto html format to produce a document with both python and R code. The rendering was smooth until I added the first python lines of python code:

```py
import requests
url = 'some/url'
page = requests.get(url)
```

The code works just fine without rendering, so I can't spot my mistake.

This is the error message from the RStudio "Background Jobs" pane:

```
Jupyter is not available in this Python installation.
Install with py -m pip install jupyter
```

Should I install jupyter, even if I'm using the knitr engine for rendering?

## EDIT (YAML section)

```yaml
---
title: "Web scrapping"
author: "Diabb Zegpi"
format: 
  html:
    self-contained: true
    theme: [default, custom.scss]
editor: visual
lang: es
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: inline
---
```

Comment: Can you share your yaml section?!

Comment: Thanks for the interest. I added the yaml.

Answer (score 3):

You can render a document with both R and python code with the `knitr` engine specified, if you have the [`{reticulate}`](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/) r-package installed in your computer. Also note that, for knitr to identify the python code you need to use `python` as the chunk header.

````
---
title: "R and Python"
format: html
engine: knitr
---

## R

```{r}
x = sample(1:100, size = 1000, replace = TRUE)
y = rnorm(1000, mean = 40, sd = 2)

plot(x, y)
```


## python

```{python}
import requests

x = requests.get('https://www.wikipedia.org/')

print(x.text)
```
````

---

[image: quarto rendered html output with R and python code]

---

Comment: As the question states, the python code ran successfully in the editor, but the rendering was failing. Suddenly, everything worked after installing jupyter. I don't know why, because I selected knitr as the engine for the quarto document, although is not specified in the YAML.

Answer (score 1):

See the [relevant quarto documentation](https://quarto.org/docs/computations/execution-options.html#engine-binding)

This suggests you need to have `engine: knitr` in your yaml

Answer (score 0):

The rendering worked after running tthe suggested line in the terminal:

```bash
py -m pip install jupyter
```

I still don't know why and what jupyter has to do with knitr rendering.